# How do I make this 'folded text' logo in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, tutorial

How can I make this logo in Photoshop? Please teach me how its possible, or give me a hint what to search for to find tutorials for similar results.

[image: example logo]

Thank you.

Comment: a simple Google for 'photoshop tutorial folded text' yields literally millions of results. Maybe some of those can help you.

Answer (score 1):

to create this logo effect you have to use the GRADIENT tool founded in photoshop and in illustrator.

If you want your logo to be vector based, work it with illustrator where you have multiple tools to draw the shape you want (e.g.: pen tool, line tool) and you can benefit from the pathfinder tool and by using it you can cut, weld, divide shape together to get the form you want.

basically the gradient tool works as follow:

It has a starting point(colour) and has an ending point(another colour) and you can include intermediate colours to get a better effect.

FOR EXAMPLE the mid section of the letter P, is just a rectangle filled with gradient based on linear style and it started as follow : DARK BLUE--->LIGHT BLUE--->DARK BLUE

you can set the colors using the gradient panel :WINDOW-->Gradient.

after doing your design you can easily export it to Photoshop and place it as smart object.

Please do not hesitate to ask me again, maybe i can do it for you and record my screen while doing it.

Best